# xpath multiple scope : select data from multiple trees

Tags: xpath, scope, nested

Problem : select data based on node which is in another part of the tree

How to select data in rows of column with label = "status"?

Data should be "data2" from `/result/rows/items/item/c/items/item/v`
and selection should be based on `label='status'` i.e. `/result/cols/items/item/label=status`

In the XML below "status" is column number 2, but it may change to column number 1, so the according XPath should return data of column no.1

```
<result>
   <cols>
      <items>
         <item>
            <id>c1</id>
            <label>result</label>
            <type>string</type>
         </item>
         <item>
            <id>c2</id>
            <label>status</label>
            <type>string</type>
         </item>
         <item>
            <id>c3</id>
            <label>message</label>
            <type>string</type>
         </item>
      </items>
   </cols>
   <rows>
      <items>
         <item>
            <c>
               <items>
                  <item>
                     <v>data1</v>
                  </item>
                  <item>
                     <v>data2</v>
                  </item>
                  <item>
                     <v />
                  </item>
               </items>
            </c>
         </item>
      </items>
   </rows>
</result>
```

Comment: what code did you try so far ?

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. Please add to your question the output you expect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your description is not very clear to understand.
I got it like this:

There is a node which indicates the column. The label of the column is "status". You get this label with

```
/result/cols/items/item/label[text()='status']
```

But that's not what you want. First, you want to find out at which position that column is. You get that position with

```
count(/result/cols/items/item[label/text()='status']/preceding-sibling::*)+1
```

But that's still not what you want. Based on that information, you want to select the actual data within rows. You get a row with

```
/result/rows/items/item/c/items/item[2]/v/text()
```

But you don't always want the second column of the row, you want the row based on the column index determined earlier. So you need to combine both:

```
/result/rows/items/item/c/items/item[count(/result/cols/items/item[label/text()='status']/preceding-sibling::*)+1]/v/text()
```

The last expression does not contain any hard coded indexes and uses only the column header text "status" to determine where the data is. In your example, it returns `data2`. If you change the column header text to "result", it gives you `data1`.

Comment: This is perfect :) . Thanx Thomas

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are asking for. But if you are looking for an Expression, which will get the "type" text for all labels with the text "status"

```
//label[text()='status']/following-sibling::type
```